# Spark: Cannot create new column from the output of filling one column null values from another

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to fill the null values from ColY with values from ColX whilst storing the output as a new column in my DataFrame Col_new.
I am using pyspark in databricks, however I am fairly new to this.

Sample Data is as follows:

```
ColX              ColY  
apple             orange
pear              null
grapefruit        pear
apple             null
```

The desired output would look like the following:

```
ColX              ColY              Col_new
apple             orange            orange  
pear              null              pear
grapefruit        pear              pear
apple             null              apple
```

I have tried several lines of code to no avail. My latest attempt was as follows:

```
.withColumn("Col_new", col('ColX').select(coalesce('ColY')))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both columns `ColY` and `ColX` should be provided as `coalesce`'s arguments:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("apple", "orange"),
  ("pear", None),
  ("grapefruit", "pear"),
  ("apple", None)
]).toDF("ColX", "ColY")

from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce

df.withColumn("ColNew", coalesce("ColY", "ColX")).show()
+----------+------+------+
|      ColX|  ColY|ColNew|
+----------+------+------+
|     apple|orange|orange|
|      pear|  null|  pear|
|grapefruit|  pear|  pear|
|     apple|  null| apple|
+----------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

`coalesce` will return the first non-null value from a list of columns. You're only passing in one column, so `coalesce` has no effect.

The correct syntax in this case would be:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce
df = df.withColumn("Col_new", coalesce('ColY', 'ColX'))
```

This means take the value of `ColY` unless it is `null`, in which case take the value from `ColX`.

In this case, you can also use `when` for the equivalent logic:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

df = df.withColumn(
    "Col_new", 
    when(col("ColY").isNull(), col("ColX")).otherwise(col("ColY"))
)
```